# Wrong value when printing variable jscript

Tags: javascript, html

So I have an array with the cards of a player, in this case I want to count the points the dealer has, the game is blackjack, in this game the dealer show his first card and the other one remains hidden, so I want to calculate the points the dealer has without the second card;

```
pontosBanca.textContent = 'Pontos : ' + calcCount(cartasBanca[0]);
```

I could do this instead of the line below

```
pontosBanca.textContent = 'Pontos : ' + calcCount(cartasBanca);
```

the problem is with the number ten whenever dealear has a 10 card the points count is always 1.

Here is the calcCount function {

```
function calcCount(cartas){

    var sum = 0;
    for(var x = 0;x<cartas.length;x++){
        if(cartas[x] === 'V' || cartas[x] === 'D' || cartas[x] === 'K' || cartas[x] === '10') sum += 10;
        else if(cartas[x] === 'A') sum += 1;
        else{

            sum += parseInt(cartas[x]);

        }

    }
    return sum;
```

note that I could remove this condition ( || cartas[x] === '10' ) beacause the else clause would produce the same result, but if I remove it the result will be 1 also.

and for last if I use this function to calculate the points of the whole dealer hand including the second card the result would be the correct one as example dealer card's : 10 and 2 the calcCount would return 12.

Hope I didn't get you too confused, new to js, thanks for any help

output if i use calcCount to count the points of only one card
http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=e7kxzq&s=9#.WLLnfTuLTsA

if i give as input the whole hand this would be the output
http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=azhun9&s=9

**note : dealer means banca**

html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>BlackJack by RuiVieira</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="zonaBanca">
        <h1>Banca</h1>
        <p id="pontosBanca">Pontos : </p>
    </div>
    <div id="zonaJogoBanca">
        <p id="jogoBanca">-</p>
    </div>
    <div id="zonaJogador">  
        <h1>Jogador</h1>
        <p id="pontosJogador">Pontos : </p>
    </div>
    <div id="zonaJogoJogador">
        <p id="jogoJogador">-</p>   
    </div>
    <div id="zonaAposta">
        <h2>Aposta</h2>
        <button id="subir">+1</button>
        <button id="parar">stop</button>
        <div>
            <input id="valorAposta" type="number" min="0" step="1"/>
        </div>
        <div>
            <button id="botaoAposta">Apostar</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="scripts/blackj.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

jscript

```
var inputvalorAposta = document.getElementById('valorAposta');
inputvalorAposta.defaultValue = 1;

botaoAposta.onclick = function() {
    var valorAposta = inputvalorAposta.value;   

    if(valorAposta = document.getElementById('valorAposta').value.length !== 0){
        var baralho = ['A','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10','V','D','K', 'A','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10','V','D','K',
            'A','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10','V','D','K', 'A','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10','V','D','K'];
        iniciaJogo(valorAposta, baralho);
    }
    else{
    }
}

function iniciaJogo(valorAposta1, baralho){

    var nrcartasJogador = 0;
    var nrcartasBanca = 0;

    var valorAposta = valorAposta1;

    var bancaCount = 0;
    var jogadorCount = 0;

    var cartasBanca = [];
    var cartasJogador = [];
    var cartasUtilizadas = [];

    var card1;

    do{
        card1 = Math.floor((Math.random() * baralho.length) + 0);
    }while(baralho[card1] === undefined);

    cartasBanca.push(baralho[card1]);
    delete baralho[card1];

    do{
        card1 = Math.floor((Math.random() * baralho.length) + 0);
    }while(baralho[card1] === undefined);

    cartasJogador.push(baralho[card1]);
    delete baralho[card1];

    do{
        card1 = Math.floor((Math.random() * baralho.length) + 0);
    }while(baralho[card1] === undefined);

    cartasBanca.push(baralho[card1]);
    delete baralho[card1];

    do{
        card1 = Math.floor((Math.random() * baralho.length) + 0);
    }while(baralho[card1] === undefined);

    cartasJogador.push(baralho[card1]);
    delete baralho[card1];

    var pontosBanca = document.getElementById('pontosBanca');
    var pontosJogador = document.getElementById('pontosJogador');

    pontosBanca.textContent = 'Pontos : ' + calcCount(cartasBanca[0]);
    pontosJogador.textContent = 'Pontos : ' + calcCount(cartasJogador);



    nrcartasJogador = 2;
    nrcartasBanca = 2;

    var jogoBanca = document.getElementById('jogoBanca');
    var jogoJogador = document.getElementById('jogoJogador');
    jogoBanca.textContent = cartasBanca[0];
    jogoBanca.textContent += ' #'; 
    jogoJogador.textContent = cartasJogador[0] + ' ';
    jogoJogador.textContent += cartasJogador[1]; 

    var butaoSubir = document.getElementById('subir');
    var butaoParar = document.getElementById('parar');

    butaoSubir.onclick = function() {

        var countCard = 0;
        for(var x = 0;x<baralho.length;x++){

            if(baralho[x] === undefined)countCard++;

        }

        if(countCard === 52)return;

        do{

            /*

            baralho tem os mesmo elementos já que o delete substui o valor por undefined, no limite o baralho é composto por 52

            */
            card1 = Math.floor((Math.random() * baralho.length) + 0);
            }while(baralho[card1] === undefined);
            cartasJogador.push(baralho[card1]);
            delete baralho[card1];
            jogoJogador.textContent += ' ' + cartasJogador[nrcartasJogador];
            nrcartasJogador++;
            if(calcCount(cartasJogador) <= 21)pontosJogador.textContent = 'Pontos : ' + calcCount(cartasJogador);
            else(pontosJogador.textContent = 'Pontos : ' + calcCount(cartasJogador) + ' Rebentou');
    }
    butaoParar.onclick = function() {

        jogoBanca.textContent = cartasBanca[0] + ' ' + cartasBanca[1];
        pontosBanca.textContent = 'Pontos : ' + calcCount(cartasBanca);

    }

}

/*

CALCULO DE PONTOS
*/
function calcCount(cartas){

    var sum = 0;
    for(var x = 0;x<cartas.length;x++){
        if(cartas[x] === 'V' || cartas[x] === 'D' || cartas[x] === 'K') sum += 10;
        else if(cartas[x] === 'A') sum += 1;
        else{

            sum += parseInt(cartas[x]);

        }

    }
    return sum;


}

/**/
```

Comment: Please show an example input.

Comment: http://tinypic.com/r/e7kxzq/9 if i calcCount using only the first card http://tinypic.com/r/azhun9/9 if i calcCount giving as parameter the whole hand

Comment: And next time, please format your code properly by indenting it by 4 spaces.

Comment: I think you a got a problem in your code, but not in this function. I just tested you function and it works perfectly, according to this test : https://jsfiddle.net/3mgfy2ky/1/

Comment: Do you actually have a `br` element in the list?

Comment: Carcigenicate what do you mean ? i'm new to this

Comment: i could share my code with you but if i post it it will not be formated...

Comment: can you see the images btw?

Comment: Copy-paste the code to the question, highlight it, and click on the `{}` icon in the toolbar to format it. Or read the [documentation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit: As an addition I have the feeling it has something to do with the fact, that a '10' needs 2 charcaters. Every other cards has only one character like '9' or 'K'

You are not building an array as an input for the calCount() function in case of a ten. It is rather the parameter '10' inseadt of ['10']

I used console.log(cartas); and console.log(sum);

```
cartas 6
sum 6
cartas ["6", "2"]
sum 8

cartas 10 //its a string not an array of strings
sum 1
cartas ["A", "4"]
sum 5
```

Comment: can you elaborate please

Comment: i thought of that before but the result for 6 for example is 6 in this case he only prints the first digit i guess, what i did was creating another function and instead of receiving an array it only receives a card and that was the solution i'm still trying to figure out a way to fuse them